# Show Contribution Note on top level of table view of contributions tab

Tags: wordpress, contributions

When you go the Contributions tab of a specific contact (under View Contact), the Note field from Additional Details of the contribution does not show up in the table. Can addtional fields, like Note, be added to this table?

The table contains Amount, Type, Source, Recevied, Thank you sent, Status and then if you uncollapse it you also see Amount, Type, Payment Method and Transaction ID.

[image]

In order to view the Note that is associated with the contribution, I have click on Activities tab and then find the specific contribution in the list and then click View to see the details and find the Note.

[image]

Is it possible to modify the columns displayed in a table in contributions tab of view contact?

EDIT: Just realized I do not need to go to Activities tab to get to the Note, but still need to click on View from the Contributions tab to see it, so still want to know if it can be displayed in the table itself.

EDIT: using v5.44.0 on WordPress.

EDIT: I think for my purposes, the SOURCE field might work fine instead of NOTES field, which already shows on top level of table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So "easy solution" was to import my Note field and put it into the Source field instead of Note as the Source is shown on the top level when viewing contributions.

This wont work if you need the Source field for something else though.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to do through GUI. If you are programmer you can add a one using pageRun() or searchColumns() hook

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Yes have some programming experience but completely new to civicrm. So will have to take some time to learn how to use the hooks you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The Form Builder extension has this as a design goal, and I expect that later this year this should be possible without code.

Since your SE history suggests you *are* a programmer, I'm going to build on Pradeep's answer.  I have a custom CiviCRM extension I just [posted to Github](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/agbucontributiontab) that adds several columns to the contribution tab - including the "Note" field.  I suspect you can get what you need by simply removing unnecessary portions.  If you're new to Civi extension coding, you can check [the documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/) but in short - you should only need to modify `agbucontribution.php`, the `.civix.php` is boilerplate.

Comment: I am brand new to civicrm so I will take a look at your custom extension and docs for intro into coding extensions.

Comment: Sounds good @jsherk - if you have questions, come chat at https://chat.civicrm.org.  This is, quite honestly, the most welcoming and non-toxic software community I've ever been a part of, you'll surely find folks willing to help you out.

Comment: @jon-g-mehaphone-tech How/where can I access the Form Builder extension?